# asp.net rewrite url logic works locally but not on server gives 404 error

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404

We are using Intelligencia UrlRewriter. All URL rewriting logic works perfectly fine on local machine using the built in visual studio server but fails on the live server. Live server has IIS 7 and Windows server 2008 Enterprise.

All rewritten urls give 404 error. If we request the aspx page with proper query strings it works.

Any special settings we need to do,check?

Comment: What are you actually wait as replay and help ? You need to see the details error from your server. The details, not just the 404.

Comment: Where? I guess there is something common that affects to all of this pages

Comment: There are details on the error, if you check the log on the server, or let the details appears - there you may see the reason. Maybe is wrong path, maybe wrong permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure your web.config file for IIS settings like:

```
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests=”true”>
            <add name=”UrlRewriter” type=”Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule” />
        </modules>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration=”false” />
    </system.webServer>
```

Please put this code block somewhere under `<configuration>` section.

I hope this will answer your question. If yes, please mark as "answered".

Comment: `<system.webServer>` webconfig section is used to specify IIS settings for this particular application.

This will ensure that the UrlRewriter.Net module from Intelligencia, which was written before IIS7 shipped, will be called and have a chance to re-write all URL requests to the server (including for folders).

Comment: What is really cool about the above web.config file is that:

1) It will work on any IIS 7.0 machine.  You don't need an administrator to enable anything on the remote host.  It will also work in medium trust shared hosting scenarios.

2) Because I've configured the UrlRewriter in both the <httpModules> and IIS7 <modules> section, I can use the same URL Rewriting rules for both the built-in VS web-server as well as on IIS7.  Both fully support extension-less URLRewriting.  This makes testing and development really easy.